# How large a library would one need to store a copy of every mathematical book and paper ever published?

Tags: soft-question

I am sure that I am not the only one who often bemoans that their university doesn't have that [extremely specific book or paper] they're looking for.

On reflection, I realise it is impractical for the library to have a copy of every mathematical text or paper...but just *how* impractical would it be?

To a rough approximation, how many textbooks and papers have been written on modern higher mathematics? How many new ones are published each year? How large a library would be needed to hold them all?

Comment: I have no way of answering you decently, but for the guys who have, I guess you will have to define what is a "mathematical book". One written by mathematicians? A book which talks about maths? A book where numbers appear?

Comment: Maybe ArXiv preprint site publishes figures on new papers and amazon on new books?

Comment: @RSerrao A first definition could just be 'a textbook written to cover a subject at the undergraduate or higher level'

Comment: You are talking about physical copies right? If digital copies are allowed, the size of one room may suffice :P

Comment: @yoyostein Let us pretend that ink and paper are very very cheap